# Execute chained bash commands including multiple pipes and grep in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, grep

I have to use the below bash command in a python script which includes multiple pip and grep commands.

```
 grep name | cut -d':' -f2  | tr -d '"'| tr -d ','
```

I tried to do the same using subprocess module but didn't succeed.

Can anyone help me to run the above command in Python3 scripts?

I have to get the below output from a file `file.txt`.

```
 Tom
 Jack
```

file.txt contains:

```
"name": "Tom",
"Age": 10

"name": "Jack",
"Age": 15
```

Actually I want to know how can run the below bash command using Python.

```
    cat file.txt | grep name | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d '"'| tr -d ','
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a bash command with parameter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521778/execute-a-bash-command-with-parameter-in-python)

Comment: Is your file json?

Answer (score 1):

This works without having to use the subprocess library or any other os cmd related library, only Python.

```
my_file = open("./file.txt")
line = True
while line:
    line = my_file.readline()
    line_array = line.split()
    try:
        if line_array[0] == '"name":':
            print(line_array[1].replace('"', '').replace(',', ''))
    except IndexError:
        pass
my_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you not trying to parse a json file or any other structured file for which using a parser would be the best approach, just change your command into:

```
grep -oP '(?<="name":[[:blank:]]").*(?=",)' file.txt
```

You do not need any pipe at all.

This will give you the **output**:

```
Tom
Jack
```

**Explanations:**

- `-P` activate perl regex for lookahead/lookbehind
- `-o` just output the matching string not the whole line
- Regex used: `(?<="name":[[:blank:]]").*(?=",)`

  - `(?<="name":[[:blank:]]")` Positive lookbehind: to force the constraint `"name":` followed by a blank char and then another double quote `"` the name followed by a double quote `"` extracted via `(?=",)` positive lookahead

**demo**: https://regex101.com/r/JvLCkO/1

Comment: Actually I want to know how can run the below bash command using Python. 

cat file.txt | grep name | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d '"'| tr -d ','